# Any recreational math involving number systems, especially binary?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, number-systems

I was asked to give a presentation on numeral systems to high school students. I'd like to sprinkle it with some recreational math. Like the game of Nim where the winning strategy is chosen according to the game's state represented as a set of binary numbers. Can you think of anything similar?

Comment: You want an impartial game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game. Examples include "Nim, Sprouts, Kayles, Quarto, Cram, Chomp, Subtract a square, Notakto, and poset games." (as said in the Wiki article).

Comment: @HiMatt I meant similar in a sense of somehow touching upon the topic of binary number system -- this isn't a presentation on combinatorial game theory.

Comment: Not a game, but if you go up to trinary and you can use a card trick: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7lP9y7Bb5g

Comment: a riddle that uses binary numbers: https://medium.com/i-math/a-king-1000-bottles-of-wine-10-prisoners-and-a-drop-of-poison-2dd1959a8dd2